# how to make a textbox show the current webbrowser url in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I tried `textBox2.Text = webBrowser1.Url.ToString();` (what the Microsoft website says) and my textbox wont show the current webbrowser URL this or i'm dumb

Comment: You do this in `webBrowser1.Navigated` event handler right?

Comment: what um, im new to c# so just uh yeah i feel cringe